# Access WAMP server remotely

Tags: android, mysql, apache, wamp, easyphp

I am working on making an Android application access data inside a MySQL database. To do this, I have recently downloaded and installed a WAMP server with EasyPHP. I have written several PHP scripts that the android application calls upon (locally of course) to manipulate data inside the database. All of this works great locally on the android emulator (using Eclipse IDE); however, I am now ready to move the project to the next phase of doing this remotely on an actual android smartphone.

Honestly, I am clueless on how I would need to go about making my EasyPHP WAMP server remote. Could someone point me in the right direction, please? Thanks.

Comment: You are going to need an actual production server environment at some point, why not get it in place to being testing?

Comment: Does your server have an IP that can be reached from the phone, e.g a local wifi address, or something from your ISP?

Comment: @StayPuff i need your help in same type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is just a browser reaching to a site.

There are some options:

- move your code to a (cheap) hoster. Some security is done by the hoster. All setup is by the hoster.
- run your own website, you need a public ip to your wamp. Most (all) of security is done by you. You need to do all of the setup.